# Why I can't achieve maximum performance with integer addition?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, optimization, x86

Here is a basic function that sums a vector of integers. When compiled using *gcc* with a third level of optimization (-O3), I can achieve **CPE 0.51** which is maximum what we can get.

```
int sum_basic(int a[], long n)
{
    int acc = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        acc += a[i];
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Here is an optimized version of this function which applies *4x4 loop unrolling*. The best I can get with this is **CPE 0.84**. I tried other types of optimization, but could not get close to **CPE 0.51**. With integer multiplication I can beat gcc, also with floating point arithmetic I can achieve maximum performance, while gcc can't. But with integer addition gcc beats me. What is the problem?

```
int sum_optimized(int a[], long n) {
    int acc1 = 0;
    int acc2 = 0;
    int acc3 = 0;
    int acc4 = 0;

    for (long i = 0; i < n; i+=4) {
        acc1 += a[i];
        acc2 += a[i+1];
        acc3 += a[i+2];
        acc4 += a[i+3];
    }

    return acc1 + acc2 + acc3 + acc4;
}
```

I use this code to measure CPE:

```
// get CPU cycle counter
static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

#define SIZE  10000
int a[SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    // cache warm up + initialize array
    for (long i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        a[i] = rand();

    long r_begin = rdtsc();
    //---------- MEASURE THIS ------------
    int res = sum_optimized(a, SIZE);
    //------------------------------------
    long r_end = rdtsc();
    long cycles = r_end - r_begin;
    double cpe = cycles / (double)SIZE;
    printf("CPE:    %.2f \n", cpe);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Did you check generated assembly?

Comment: I bet the optimizer figures out what you are doing, and vectorizes the additions for you. Check generated assembly to see what is going on.

Comment: @md5 Yes, but for the basic function it is impossible to understand what it does. It has a lot of jumps somewhere.

Comment: You don't need 4 acccumulators.

Comment: @Graduate: Still you can check whether vectorized instructions are generated ([ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)).

Comment: @md5 I don't see any of these commands. Actually gcc uses xmm registers form my slow optimized version.

Comment: @Graduate With clang 3.8, I get 0.25 CPE for the `sum_basic` function. Clang optimizes it just fine. gcc does so, too.

Comment: @FUZxxl You probably have a more sophisticated CPU. What is your CPE for sum_optimized?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. If 0.5 CPE is the best your CPU can do whats wrong with using your first program to achieve it? Why do you need to find a less obvious and less clear way to doing it?

Comment: Measuring "cycles" with `rdtsc` is garbage. One, you're not guaranteed to remain on the same core through the execution of the program. Two, `rdtsc` doesn't count processor cycles unless you have an ancient non-constant TSC processor. Three, `rdtsc` is not serializing. There may be more issues, but that's from the top of my head.

Comment: @md5:  They both auto-vectorize, but there actually *is* an answer for part of why sum_optimized does such a bad job.  IDK why gcc makes such clunky code for the loop counter / pointer.

Comment: What hardware did you test on?  What exact gcc version and options?  (Any `-mtune=native` or `-march=native` or anything?).  These are critical things to include in a question about explaining microbenchmark performance.  It happens that I was able to answer it without that, based on what I think is a good guess, but you got lucky.

Comment: the posted code for unrolling the loop has a few problems  1) the array much be exactly a multiple of 4 in element count, otherwise the resulting sum will not be correct.  2) use a pointer that is incremented rather than calculating the offset into the array for each 'add' operation. 3) there only needs to be a single 'sum' not 4 different sums

Comment: @user3629249: Using multiple accumulators is actually a *good* thing, especially with higher-latency operations like FP add.  Using 4 scalar accumulators would probably let this loop vectorize with `float` or `double` without `-ffast-math`.  (Of course, ideal FP code would use multiple *vector* accumulators to bottleneck on vector FP add throughput instead of latency).  You're right that a pointer increment instead of array indexing might have got gcc to make better code in this case.  Normally it doesn't matter, but gcc seems to have failed here.

Answer (score 4):

TL:DR: this might be a known missed-optimization bug (gcc doesn't do associative-math optimizations with signed integers), combined with plain old compilers not actually being artificially intelligent and generating slow code.

---

First of all, **RDTSC measures wall-clock time, not necessarily core clock cycles**.  Use perf counters to measure core clock cycles in microbenchmarks so you don't have to worry about CPU frequency scaling.  (Unless your microbenchmark involves L2 cache misses, because the same time in nanoseconds is more clock cycles at higher frequency.  i.e. high frequency means cache misses hurt more, and main memory bandwidth is lower in bytes per cycle.)

---

gcc 5.3 (with no `-march=nehalem` or `-mtune=haswell` or anything) auto-vectorizes the basic version to its usual choice of scalar until an alignment boundary, and then the vectorized inner loop:

From the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fverbose-asm+',sourcez:JYOwLgBAzgrgtgfQPYAczDsAXgUwCYAUokAhgNoC6ANBADZIgDmEIAlBAN4BQEvExEEgGMhARggBeCAAYA3Dz4DhQgEySZ8vv3CCRAZnVyFvJSIAsh%2BcYgAzJACcIBek36W3AHhaz%2BAaglm7NxaWsri/oJkwBSaIbzKahHkwL6iMdah%2BhBJUb4q6XHx5tlSyb56BXwAvlzW9jhgMPYgumLZrYmtBr6tZvI1XAKwiABGJFDAQkQ65NR0DMxsXMGKMyKW1naOzgtuUnKe3n6%2BQRl8yiWR0bG8NVr1jc2t/bVAAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
 # gcc5.3  -O3 -fverbose-asm   (-mtune=generic; only SSE2 because no -march used)

 sum_basic:
 ... scalar prologue
.L14:   ### inner loop
    add     rdx, 1    # ivtmp.39,
    paddd   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [r9]        # vect_acc_10.34, MEM[base: _156, offset: 0B]
    add     r9, 16    # ivtmp.40,
    cmp     r8, rdx   # bnd.28, ivtmp.39
    ja      .L14        #,

  ... horizontal sum and scalar epilogue
```

So, silly gcc, keeping two separate loop counters instead of just checking for `r9` getting to `a+n`.  Or at least looping with `dec rdx / jnz` to avoid the `cmp`.  But no, so the loop has 4 fused-domain uops, all of them needing an ALU port.  So it can issue at one iteration per clock on Intel Core2 and later, but only execute at once iteration per clock on Haswell and later (which added a 4th ALU port).

On SnB and later, an unroll with two vector-ALUs would double the throughput for small arrays, because `PADDD` has one cycle latency but two (or three) per cycle throughput, and so do loads.  On larger arrays, you'd still just bottleneck on memory bandwidth.

---

When you manually unroll with 4 accumulators, gcc decides to preserve those semantics, and just use unaligned loads in the inner loop.  gcc 5.3 unfortunately ends up doing a really bad job:

```
# gcc5.3 -O3 -fverbose-asm   (-mtune=generic, same lack of enabling SSE4/AVX/AVX2)
sum_optimized:
   zero xmm0 and some other minor setup
.L3:
    mov     rdx, rax
    add     rax, 1
    sal     rdx, 4           # what the hell gcc?  just add 16 instead of copying and shifting a separate instructions.  Even if it takes two loop counters like in the basic version.
    cmp     rcx, rax         # cmp not next to ja, can't macro-fuse.  (-mtune=haswell fixes this)
    movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rdx]    # separate load, not folded into paddd because it's unaligned.
    paddd   xmm0, xmm1
    ja      .L3
    ...
    A hilarious horizontal sum that uses MOVD on each element separately and sums with scalar integer ops.  (With -march=nehalem, it uses PEXTRD)
```

This is 7 fused-domain uops on Intel Nehalem and later.  On Core2, it's 9 uops IIRC.  Pre-Nehalem, movdqu was multiple uops and ran slower than movdqa even if the data was aligned at run-time.

Anyway, assuming Nehalem or later, this can issue at one iteration per 2 cycles, and that's the bottleneck.  Execution could handle up to 6 ALU uops per 2 cycles.  Even if the pointer isn't aligned, that shouldn't slow it down any more, because gcc's code is so slow already.

---

**My theory is that it's because of a known missed-optimization bug in gcc**: adding the numbers in a different order would lead to overflow.  Everything would actually work out in the end thanks to 2's complement, but gcc doesn't know how to take advantage of that.  Signed overflow in C is undefined behaviour, but not on x86.

In Richard Biener's response to [my gcc bug report about gcc not doing associative-math optimizations on signed-int `a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69943), he said:

> It's a long-standing issue that reassoc doesn't associate !
>   TYPE_OVERFLOW_WRAPS chains.It's a long-standing issue that reassoc
>   doesn't associate ! TYPE_OVERFLOW_WRAPS chains.  It could do that to a
>   limited extent (only cancelling ops that don't affect overflow) or
>   fully if it re-writes the operation to unsigned arithmetic at commit
>   time.  Some way of detecting desired vs. just canonicalization
>   transforms is required to avoid rewriting all signed integer ops into
>   unsigned (well, maybe it's not that bad actually, who knows).

The horizontal-sum algorithms used by the two versions lend some weight to this theory: sum_basic uses a normal shift-down-the-high-half and vector-add.  sum_optimized extracts each vector element separately.

---

#### How to make this run even faster:

Compile with `-march=native`, especially if you have a CPU which supports AVX2.

As I mentioned earlier, multiple *vector* accumulators could, with the right amount of unrolling, give you two loads and two 128 or 256b vector adds per clock on Intel SnB-family or AMD K10 or newer.  (IIRC, AMD K8 could do two loads per clock, but didn't have 128b-wide execution units.)

As always, it matters what hardware you run a microbenchmark on, and what array size!

Comment: Do L2 miss times really not scale with frequency? I.e., an L2 miss is relatively constant time, not constant cycles? I though L3 would be the first level that is constant time rather than constant cycles (since L2 is on-die and runs at chip frequency, IIRC).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yeah, I think L2 runs at chip frequency, so L2 *hits* are constant latency in cycles.  I was thinking that L3 might be in a different clock domain, so L2 misses (which have to check L3) are not constant latency (in cycles).  But I'm actually not sure about that; I don't remember seeing ranges for L3 latency.

Comment: Ah right, I read that as "misses to L2", but you wrote (and meant) L2 misses (i.e., at least to L3). I'm also not sure about L3 misses - they have switched back and forth in recent architectures from being synchronous with the CPU clock and being in another domain, but in the latter case I'm not sure if the domain scales with CPU frequency.